# want to draw rectangle using canvas html5 but this rectangle bent arch shape like in picture

Tags: html, canvas

[image]

want  to  draw  rectangle using canvas html5 but  this rectangle  bent arch shape  like  in picture

Answer (score 0):

use quadraticCurveTo(x,y,Bx,By);

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(200, 200);
  context.quadraticCurveTo(400, 300, 600, 200);
  context.quadraticCurveTo(500, 300, 600, 400);
  context.quadraticCurveTo(400, 300, 200, 400);
  context.quadraticCurveTo(300, 300, 200, 200);
  context.closePath();
  // line color
  context.lineWidth = 10;
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.stroke();
  context.fillStyle = 'green';
  context.fill();
```

http://codepen.io/hamed19/pen/QyXbNp

Answer (score 0):

You can create a path with quadratic curves for everything except the left & right sides (lines):

[image]

**Example code and a Demo:**

*Using styling to mimic the question's image*

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

drawArchedRect(10,10,330,192,10,25,'lightgray','gray');

function drawArchedRect(x,y,w,h,offset,dipy,strokecolor,shadow){

  ctx.translate(x,y);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(offset,0);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(offset+w/2,dipy ,w-offset,0);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(w,0, w,offset);
  ctx.lineTo(w,h-offset);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(w,h,  w-offset,h);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(offset+w/2,h-dipy ,offset,h);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(0,h, 0,h-offset);
  ctx.lineTo(0,offset);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(0,0, offset,0);

  ctx.save();

  if(shadow){
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.shadowColor=shadow;
    ctx.shadowBlur=5;
  }
  ctx.strokeStyle=strokecolor;
  ctx.lineWidth=1.5;
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.restore();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=300></canvas>
```